# Would "pentaminutely" reflect an event that occurs every five minutes?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, time, compounds, recurring-events

Would the compound *pentaminutely* (from *penta-* and *minutely*) be correct in describing an event that occurs every five-minutes? Or is there a better word?

**Edit:** For clarity, I'm looking to name an object in a programming model so it is clear by the name what the object represents. I am trying to avoid writing a short novel to describe the name in the object model.

Comment: Time is measured with Latin words (quinquennium, century, mensural, diurnal), so I guess at *quinqueminutal*. But "every five minutes" is far more easily understood!

Comment: Thanks Andrew; normally I would agree, but I'm naming domain objects and want to be as concise as possible with the names... admittedly _quinqueminutal_ isn't much more concise than the phrase! :)

Comment: "I'm looking to name an object in a programming model so it is clear by the name what the object represents." So... if you don't know for sure, it will never be clear to anyone reading the code either, unless they Google it and find this discussion.

Comment: As an aside, is it wise to name your object with a 'configuration-data'-type name?  What if later you decide that 5 minutes isn't quite right and that every 320 seconds is better?

Comment: Without getting into too much of the implementation details, the object itself is an implementation on top of another, abstracted, object that allows for variance in time. The only way we would go is down, and then it would be per minute which is probably too minute (heh...) for the application. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: @KenAspeslagh I was actually going to address this point in my above edit but omitted it. The desire is to have a name that describes what the object is doing or its purpose (thus, achieving clarity) even if the term may be conceived as arcane.

Comment: *Yearly, monthly, weekly, daily, hourly.* I don't accept *minutely* or *secondly*, and I can't think of any other adjectival forms created from timespan nouns. Whatever - OP's requirement seems Too Localised to me. [25 instances](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22minutely+intervals%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22minutely+intervals%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=2Pz9UKrdK8yR0QWJuoHoDA&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1254&bih=886) of (imho, sloppy wording) *minutely intervals* isn't enough to justify *pentaminutely*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure what your objection to [_minutely_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/minutely) is. It's an old, probably archaic, word but that doesn't make it any less legitimate.

Comment: @SeanQuinn it's certainly a word that's been around for hundreds of years, so I'd accept it, but it is archaic so as I say in my answer, it's best avoided in the majority of uses.

Comment: @SeanQuinn: I reject it on the grounds that *virtually nobody ever uses it*. Compare, for example, the 8 instances of [five minutely intervals](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22five+minutely+intervals%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) with 185,000 instances of [five minute intervals](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22five+minute+intervals%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I don't accept that *minutely* is or ever was valid in this context. Obviously almost everyone else agrees with me, or it would have been used a lot more often.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would agree that _minutely intervals_ would be incorrect in its usage. It is redundant. In this case I think you're right _five minute intervals_ would be more correct. However, to describe a passage of time with a singularly descriptive word, I think Jon Hanna's answer is the correct one--particularly for this denomination of time. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: The TL;DR of this page is "Yes, but no one uses it and most wouldn't understand."  Incidentally, we just had a chat in my department about an old use of "pentaminutely" in our system.  Three of four in our team understood it.

Comment: I would take it to mean a tiny pentagon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean every 3 hectoseconds?

Uncommon combinations of multipliers and time units are made use of in a tongue-in-cheek manner in some communities (one VMS setting was measured in microfortnights), and in those *pentaminutely* would be guessed at and the unusual construction appreciated with smiles or groans.

Outside of those, it would not. Even *five-minutely* has issues, since *minutely* is rarely used (presumably because it can be confused with *minutely* meaning by a very small amount).

A great way of expressing this would be "repeating every five minutes". In some technical contexts, then "repeating with a five-minute period" would work well, but the sense of *period* that refers to a regularly repeating interval isn't as well known as other senses, so it wouldn't serve as well for all audiences.

Edit:

Just say your edit on it being in a computer object model. *pentaminute* would be fine if your coding standards allow a modicum of humour in naming. Otherwise fiveMinuteRepeater or fiveMinutePeriod etc. is clear and to the point.

(Incidentally, *hectosecond* is an SI unit that complies fine with ISO 8000. Just don't actually ever use it for anything).

Comment: The distance between *pentaminute* and *penultimate* seems almost ridiculously close. :)  As for the other, sounds like a *heck of a second* thought.

Comment: @tchrist which while a good reason not to use then 99% of the time, makes them all the funnier for the tongue-in-cheek use.

Comment: I first read ISO 8000 as a film speed. :)

Comment: @tchrist, ah, that would be interpreting "ISO 8000" as an ISO 12232 film speed that you would decide upon after consulting an ISO 2720 light meter. I can remember a disturbingly large quantity of these numbers, but admit I had to look those up. It is a tad ambiguous that the speeds are referred to in the same format as the standards themselves.